# How to make an activity not backtrack to previous activity

Tags: java, android

I made a basic android app which consists of 3 activities; A,B and C. A is the main activity. That's the first activity that is launched when you first start the app. There is a button inside A in which it sends an intent to open B. In B, the user can select their difficiulty etc. And once selected, C gets called. C is where the main game occurs. Once the user finishes the game, a score dialog pops up and displays the user score.

Right now, when the user presses ok, the dialog just dissapears and the user is still on C. If he presses the back button then B gets called. How do I make it such that when the user presses OK on the score dialog box, it send him to A and also if he presses the back button on A (he is trying to go back to C from A), how do I prevent that from happening?

EDIT = One question, I am using shared preferences in my C activity and there is a continue button on my A activity. When the user completes C, I want to destory the save file (brainData) and then proceed to A. I am destorying the save file by `SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("brainData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); pref.edit().clear().commit();` but when I press continue on A activity, it still loads the file. I am writing to the save file in the onPause() of C actvity fyi.

Answer (score 0):

On the dialog's OK button, add an Intent to start Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks ok just add:

```
startActivity(new Intent(C.this, A.class));
finish();
```

or if you don't want to finish C in A just override these methods:

```
@Override // 2.0 and above
public void onBackPressed()
{

}

@Override // Before 2.0
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In activity A and B you can overwrite the method `onPause()` and in that you need to call `finish()`. This will finish() activity A when B is started & finish B when C is started. Also add `onPause()` to C. Code below

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause()
   {
   super.onPause();
   finish();
   }
   ```
2. For sending to A again when dialog button is clicked use below code to start Activity A again

   ```
   startActivity(new Intent(C.this, A.class));
   ```
3. For deleting sharedpreference when ok button is clicked in onclick method do

   ****Removing all preferences:

   ```
   SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   settings.edit().clear().commit();
   ```

****Removing single preference:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.edit().remove("KeyName").commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The finish() works. One question, I am using shared preferences in my C activity and there is a continue button on my A activity. When the user completes C, I want to destory the save file (brainData) and then proceed to A. I am destorying the save file by `SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("brainData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            pref.edit().clear().commit();` but when I press continue on A activity, it still loads the file. I am writing to the save file in the onPause() of C actvity fyi.

Comment: You need to handle sharedpreference when the ok button is clicked. first handle sharedprefence then startactivity A. Do you want to just remove the repference??? if so see my edit. and edit the question of yours too to add about sharedpreferences

Comment: I want to remove the preference. basically there should be no trace of a saved data

Comment: your coding is correct for removing preferences just add it in onclick og ok button of dialog

Comment: I realised I don't have the context keywork in my code. When I write it to my code, i get an error 'cannot resolve keyword context'

Comment: Its Context not context @TarikhChouhan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103446/discussion-between-tarikh-chouhan-and-zahan-safallwa).

Answer (score 0):

Add flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when starting activity B.

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class); 
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

The second way to do it is to add parameter `android:noHistory="true"` to activity B in your manifest file.

This will prevent B from appearing in backstack.

Other answers just adding another A activity to stack, but not removing B from it.

To leave activity C when press OK button in score dialog, just call `activity.finish()` in the OK button click listener.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated the question. Do you mind having a look at it? Thank you.